# Android Kotlin recyclerview with EditText

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

I have a recyclerview where each view contains a TextView and an EditText. The part where I am stuck is when I start typing in any of the row's EditText box, it automatically updates another row further down the list. I know this is occurring because of the whole recycling aspect of recyclerview and the same view is re-used for the rows further down. I just don't know how to implement this correctly.

Comment: create a string list and change it position-wise using text watcher

Comment: sorry I am not following, could you elaborate more please? Right now, I have a textwatcher where I have the 3 override methods and I am reading the user's entered text in AfterTextChanged method.

Comment: just find out the use of array string with recycleview. After finding out those array position is used to set that text view and update the same array position value in text watcher

Answer (score 1):

```
class TodoAdapter(private val tasks : List<TodoItem>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    inner class ViewHolder(private val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        var editText = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edit_text)


        init {
            editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher{
                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                    tasks[adapterPosition].task = s.toString()
                }

                override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

                }

                override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

                }

            })
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.todo_item,parent,false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = tasks.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val item = tasks[position]
        holder.editText.setText(item.task)
    }
}

class TodoItem(var task: String = "")

 editText.addTextChangedListener(object TextWatcher() {
    
       override fun afterTextChanged(s : Editable) {
          item.textFieldValue = s.toString()
       }
  });
```

Put textChangeListener inside init block this should work

Comment: So, I tried that approach and it only works when I try adding something into EditText on my first attempt. As soon as I do it again on another row (2nd time), I see a another row further down with the same value.

Comment: that worked... bless your soul!! If you dont mind could you explain why this worked? moving it from bindViewHolder to the init block

Comment: Listener was keep adding in onBindVIewHolder since we want to add listener only once so we moved to addTextChangeListener in init block. you need to understand how recycler view works internally. https://blog.mindorks.com/how-does-recyclerview-work-internally

Answer (score 0):

@MuhammadAhmed

Data class

```
class todolist(var hours: String, var task: String)
```

Adapter

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoAdapter.TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val currentItem = todo[position]
    holder.todo.text = currentItem.hours
    holder.task.text = currentItem.task
    holder.task.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher{
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            currentItem.task = s.toString()
        }
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
    })
}
```